# Pasting Date From Excel into Date field that you cannot CTRL+V

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to paste a date using the form 03012017 into the date form with a code of: 
`<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$response_def06a4c-a2c3-4120-a165-7ed24d106c6e" value="__/__/____" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_response_def06a4c-a2c3-4120-a165-7ed24d106c6e" class="textboxcontrol" type="text">`

I'm using selenium on eclipse and I am trying to put the date that is in the excel sheet pasted into a form that does not allow ctrl+v so either using the sendkeys(); method in which I have tried but failed or by right clicking and selecting the paste option.

The code that I have so far is: 
if(Headers[a].equals("datePartA")){ 
                String v_datePartA = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(a));

```
                // driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_response_def06a4c-a2c3-4120-a165-7ed24d106c6e")).clear();
                // driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_response_def06a4c-a2c3-4120-a165-7ed24d106c6e")).click();

               StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(v_datePartA);
               System.out.println("stringSelection is " + stringSelection);

                Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
                clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
                System.out.println("Clipboard is " + stringSelection);

                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_response_def06a4c-a2c3-4120-a165-7ed24d106c6e")));

                WebElement Paste = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_response_def06a4c-a2c3-4120-a165-7ed24d106c6e"));
                Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
                //driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_response_def06a4c-a2c3-4120-a165-7ed24d106c6e")).click();

                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_response_def06a4c-a2c3-4120-a165-7ed24d106c6e")));
             driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_response_def06a4c-a2c3-4120-a165-7ed24d106c6e")).click();

                builder.contextClick(Paste).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

I am also using firefox if that helps any.

Thank you!